# php date formatting not working

Tags: php

```
$t = DateTime::createFromFormat('Gi', '900');
$time_str = $t->format('gi a');
echo $time_str; //outputs 600 pm instead of 9am. Why? and How do I get 9am?
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong.. I am following what is given here in terms of date formatting:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Thanks!

Comment: no idea why but this works > `DateTime::createFromFormat('G i', '9 00');` i guess its because the time must be separated in some way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you linked is for the [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function. The [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is not the same (though the format strings are pretty much identical).

I expect the format parsing is having trouble recognizing the difference between the hour and minute components.

If you split them up with a space, you get the desired result:

```
$t = DateTime::createFromFormat('G i', '9 00');
$time_str = $t->format('gi a');
echo $time_str;
// Output is 900 am
```

**Edit:**

The inability for PHP to parse a format string like `Gi` is a [known bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55240). The parser for `G` doesn't know whether to read `9` or `90` and in the latter case that `90` is too high.

Comment: Ah thanks! that helps! Thing is, for quick computation of time (and because I need to use them as array indices), I am storing them as numbers [0 to 2359]. So the best way to convert them to am/pm for printing would be to split them to hour and min, subtract 12 etc?

Comment: If you pad the time string with a leading zero, it seems to parse that correctly. `0900` = 900 am However I would strongly consider putting a colon between the hours and minutes components of the output time when using am/pm, as it is standard formatting.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But 01000 fails. It was simpler to just do it manually :)

Comment: Well you wouldn't pad a 4-digit time; only when the hour component is 1 digit. Padding generally implies adding characters so that output is a fixed-width across expected values. Example: `str_pad($time, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Answer (score 2):

As i said in my comment this works :

```
$t = DateTime::createFromFormat('G i', '9 00');
$time_str = $t->format('gi a');
echo $time_str.PHP_EOL;
```

Cannot find any where written down - but suspect the time needs to be separated ... either by space or colon or something else

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Good answer! ;)

Comment: Thanks! I accepted the other answer because of the link to the bug :)